# SQL Server: Using OPENROWSET Results Inside an IN() Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `.CSV` file containing thousands of SKUs. I would like to lookup the available quantities in my database for only the SKUs listed within this `.CSV` file.

Here's what I have so far: (Let's say a couple SKUs are named "ABC" and "XYZ")

The SQL (on SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
SELECT 
    [sku], [qty]
FROM 
    [Inventory]
WHERE 
    [sku] IN (SELECT skuColumn 
              FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\skus.csv',
                              FORMATFILE='C:\skusFormat.xml') AS data)
```

The CSV file (skus.csv):

```
ABC
XYZ
...
```

The XML format file (skusFormat.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
        <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" MAX_LENGTH="40" />
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="sku" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR" />
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

When I run the `SELECT... OPENROWSET()` statement on its own, a single column of SKUs is returned - as expected; however, when I use it as a subquery within `IN()` the results are empty.

I'm expecting the results to be the SKUs from the `skus.csv` file and their quantities from the `Inventory` database. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: could be data type mismatch... nvarchar from csv but from the table?

Comment: That sounds plausible. The `sku` column in the database is type `CHAR`. How would I go about casting all of the SKU values as a certain data type?

I've tried setting the `COLUMN` element in the format file to `xsi:type`s SQLCHAR, SQLVARYCHAR, SQLNCHAR, and SQLNVARCHAR but the results are still empty.

Comment: please check my answer see if that will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be data type mismatched 
and using EXISTS instead of IN

```
SELECT [sku], [qty]
FROM [Inventory] x
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'C:\skus.csv',
        FORMATFILE='C:\skusFormat.xml'
    ) AS data
    where cast(data.skuColumn as char(10)) = x.sku
)
```